# SQL Server: Slow restore from SQL 2014 DB, but Fast from SQL 2016 DB via SSMS

Tags: sql-server

We are chasing an odd problem.

We see a significant perf delta when restoring via SSMS, but do NOT see the delta when restoring via TSQL.

When we restore, using SSMS, on SQL 2016 from a DB created on a SQL 2014 instance, the restore is really really slow.

But, on the same SQL 2016 DB server, when we restore from a SQL 2016 instance, again in SSMS, the restore is super fast.

The SQL 2016 system is a super fast system, all-SSD, etc. It should always be fast.

To address, we applied all OS and SQL patches and updates to the target system. Problem was not changed.

Why would restoring a SQL 2014 DB be so slow?

Comment: Because when you restore database between different version the Engine make the conversion in the system files make slower.

Comment: Also may want to check this:   https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158506/sql-server-2016-slow-restore

Comment: Have you generated the script that the SSMS version is using and compared that with your T-SQL script?

Answer (score 3):

The restore from 2014 is an upgrade, not just a restore.  You should actually see this in the messages window, assuming you are using T-SQL to do the restore.   You don't mention what Fast and Slow are, or the differences, such as 5 mins vs. 5 hours, so we can't add much to this.

Comment: Apologies, we were missing an important aspect, OP updated.

Comment: "Really fast" and "super slow" don't mean anything.   T-SQL in the SSMS query window vs. SSMS GUI?  No matter how you are doing it, you are still upgrading the 2014 to 2016.   Database size?