# SQL Server Restore Disk Response Time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

So I have a new SQL Server in place.  I have a 200GB database I am trying to restore to this new server and the restore time is taking longer than my current server.  My new server has a RAID 10 for the database files, a RAID 1 for the log files and a RAID 5 (where the backup files are located).  I can't seem to figure this out. When I try and copy files directly to the RAID 10, I am getting copying speeds to 1.2GB/sec, but when restoring through SSMS, (looking at the resource monitor), it is only moving at like 50MB/sec.  I just can't figure what is happening here.  Anyone have any tips?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Where is it reading the backup file from?  When you did the copy test, was the source location the same as where the backup file is?  Is the database encrypted?  It is about 1000x more likely to be a hardware or network issue than a SQL Server issue, so I would recommend very thorough testing of all file systems and networks that are used in the restore process.

Comment: Backup file is on RAID 5.  Yes the source location is the same for the straight file copy and the restore.  Database is not encrypted.

Comment: Does the SQL Server service account have the Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks permission so that it can use instant file initialization?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-instant-file-initialization?view=sql-server-ver15 and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158506/sql-server-2016-slow-restore

Comment: Also note that if the server has a lot of security restrictions in place with group policy, etc., you may have given it the Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks permission during installation, but it could have failed or been wiped out the next time group policies were updated.

Comment: Yes, it has Volume Maintenance Task permission.  I double checked it and it is still there.  Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: [Resource Governor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor?view=sql-server-ver15#resource-governor-constraints) could throttle IO resources. Do you have it configured on that server?

Answer (score 1):

So the answer ended up being bad raid controller.  I had a Dell tech come out and replace the raid controller and drives.  Then there was a setting in the Dell configuration to allow the dual raid controllers to work independently.